# Visual Studio 2022 with Android Emulator - Stop Debugging Expected Behavior

Tags: visual-studio

I'm running .net Maui app using Visual Studio 2022 with android emulator.
The problem I'm facing is when I stop debugging android emulator closes.

This results in extra delays the next time I want to start debugging.
I have to wait for the android emulator to launch, and sometimes there are deployment issues and I have to try to start debugging multiple times.

Additionally after the app starts and is connected to the debugger I have to login to authenticate to underlying api. I'm not exactly sure what this happens. I do know that calls to AcquireTokenSilent work if close the app and re open the app.  Calling AcquireTokenSilent after a device power cycle results in an exception and requires AcquireTokenInteractive to be used.

I would like to be able to keep the device open in the android emulator when I stop debugging in Visual studio.  This would speed development time.

Is there a way to do this?

I expect the device emulator to continue to run after I stop debugging.